# Why Does Firebase orderByChild() return undefined?

Tags: firebase

I've got a Firebase with a simple bit of data:

[image: Firebase screenshot]

There's a list of "players", each with a self-generated GUID, and each containing a value "Count". At my request (e.g. using `once()`), I want to be able to query the players sorted by the `Count` value. So, based on the [Firebase documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html), I'm using `orderByChild()`, but it always comes up as undefined when I run the code:

```
var fb = new Firebase("https://morewhitepixels.firebaseio.com/");
fb.child("players").orderByChild("Count").once("value",function(data) {
  // do something with data
});
```

But this code always returns `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` pointing to that second line of code.

What am I missing?

Comment: What version of the Firebase libraries are you using? Most likely it is < 2.0, while the `orderByChild` function was introduced in 2.0.

Comment: yes, this was my problem. can't believe I didn't see it. was using an older version of the library. thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure what you do inside the callback, but this works fine:

```
fb.child("players").orderByChild("Count").once("value",function(data) { 
    console.log(data.val()); 
});
```

Keep in mind that the `data` parameter is not the actual data yet. It's a `DataSnapshot` on which you have to call `val()` first.

You'll probably want to loop through the children, which you can do like this:

```
fb.child("players").orderByChild("Count").once("value",function(data) { 
    data.forEach(function(snapshot) {
        console.log(snapshot.val().Count); 
    });
});
```

The above example prints out all your children in the order you requested:

```
120320
181425
185227
202488
202488
202488
202488
245197
245197
487320
```

Alternatively you can use `on('child_added'` instead:

```
fb.child("players").orderByChild("Count").on("child_added",function(snapshot) { 
    console.log(snapshot.val().Count); 
});
```